# How to keep url parameters as key-value

Tags: c#, httpcontext, url-parameters

Normally I can read a parameter inurl with httpcontext but I wonder if there is more than one query parameter in the url can I obtain them as key-value?

> url: localhost:3034/?CustomerID=12345&RoleName=Student

```
string customerID = this.HttpContext.Request["CustomerID"];
string roleName= this.HttpContext.Request["RoleName"];
```

Do I have the chance to hold it as key-value instead of reading it one by one like above and use it anywhere in the project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you wanting it as "Key-Value" because you want to iterate all params? They are currently key value, in that you feed in the key of CustomerId and get back the value.

Comment: The Item[String] collection is a combination of QueryString, Form, Cookies and ServerVariables collections. I think OP is just looking for the QueryString collection which, strangely, doesn't seem to be exposed as a NameValueCollection like the others.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning actually it is.  It's the QueryString property.

Comment: @Xipooo ... which is a String property, not a NameValueCollection.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I assure you it is :)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.querystring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpRequest_QueryString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just access the Headers property of the Response object directly for headers or QueryString property for query parameters.  They're both already a collection:

```
NameValueCollection headers = this.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
NameValueCollection queryParams = this.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
```

Comment: The Request.Headers collection contains the HTTP Headers from the incoming HTTP Request. It doesn't contain the QueryString values.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning good point. He would have to use Headers for header values, QueryString for querystring values, etc. Updated to include query string parameters too.

Comment: Thanks for your support @Xipooo I can reach the parameter values with "QueryString"